# Как сделать редирект на мобильную версию?

Tags: redirect, мобильная-разработка

Очень слабо понимаю в хостингах, в механике работы серверов и прочего, а уж тем более в переадресации. Могу только верстать немного. Сверстал одностраничный сайт,и вот в чем проблема: использую скрипт который не смотрится в мобильной версии и всячески её ломает. Решил что не смогу адаптировать данное и быстрее будет сделать отдельную мобильную версию сайта (< 768px). 
Пожалуйста обьясните очень доходчиво, как и что сделать. Вот сайт donsocks.ru
Пользуюсь cPanel на хосте. Спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: Сделай для мобильной версии под-домен m.donsocks.ru потом на главной donsocks.ru сделай детект, по юзер агентам и т д, и если это мобильный или планшет, перенаправляй на m.donsocks.ru Но если ты делаешь все на одном домене то лучше сделать адаптивный дизайн.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно подключить библиотеку для определения мобильных устройств http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Далее на страницах сайта в начале добавить:

```
<?php
  include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

  if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header('Location: yourpage.php'); // страница для переадресации
    exit(0);
  }
?>
```

Примеры использования https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/wiki/Code-examples

Comment: я могу вставить это, если у меня index.html а не php?

Comment: @rounezzzzz можно изменить формат файла и тогда будет работать. Вместо `index.html` сделать `index.php`.

Comment: я добавил, спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

Думаю можно вставить код на php

```
header( 'Location: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=redirect', true, 301 ); 

// сделать переадресацию с помощью 301 редиректа на поиск в Яндексе слова redirect.


header( 'Location: http://google.ru/search?q=redirect' ); // с помощью 302 редиректа переадресовывать на поиск в гугле слова redirect (При использовании Location без указания кода редиректа, по умолчанию используется 302-й).


header( 'Location: /article/page.htm', true, 303 ); // с помощью 303 редиректа переадресовать на внутреннюю страницу сайта.


header( 'Location: /', true, 307 ); // перебросить на главную страницу сайта с использованием 307 редиректа.


header( 'Refresh: 5; url=http://rambler.ru/' ); // переадресовать на главную страницу Рамблера через 5 секунд после загрузки страницы.


header( 'Refresh: 0; url=/error404.html' ); // переадресовать на страницу ошибки немедленно (без задержки).
```

Я в php не силен, но вроде последний метод хорошо подойдет)